# How to be informed about Quip incidences?

Tags: quip

Quip is not included in trust.salesforce.com. I would like to be alerted of Quip incidences. Where can I check, or subscribe, or receive this information? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might also want to post this question on [Quip group](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/groups/0F93A000000LgciSAC?tab=discussion&sort=LAST_MODIFIED_DATE_DESC)

Comment: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdoxeUAB/add-quip-status-to-httpstrustsalesforcecom